# Spring How can I take only one of two params given?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to create a Spring controller where I retrieve 4 params: Id, Name, Description and Qty but I need only take Id or Name, if user send both is wrong, How Can I do this?

Im trying followgin:

```
@GetMapping(value="/purchase")
public model purchase(@Valid @PathVariable String Id, 
    @Valid @PathVariable String Name){
  ...
}
```

Comment: path variable is required but in your url you don't define.

Comment: Why don't you use @RequestParams ?

Comment: Use `params="name,!id"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure in code, that only one parameter (id or name, but not both) is sent to your method. Instead of path variables you should use query parameters in your GET method. So a solution could look like this:

```
@GetMapping("/purchase")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getItemByName(@RequestParam(required = false) String name, 
        @RequestParam(required = false) String id) {
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(name) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(id))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only on parameter allowed.");
    ...
```

Then you can test you method with calls like these:

- http://localhost:8080/purchase?name=ball&id=123
- http://localhost:8080/purchase?id=123

In my German blog I wrote an article about how to create RestController in Spring and how you can handle parameters, this might give you more background information:
https://agile-coding.blogspot.com/2020/10/rest-json-apis-in-java-leicht-gemacht.html